# Get the result of a callback function which is having async/await

Tags: javascript

I am stuck in a js function.

```
function test() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('hrllo')
        return "I love You !!";
    }, 3000);
}

function main() {
    var result = test();
    console.log(result);     // must be I love You !!
}
```

I am working in pure Js which is JS 2017 supported means we can use async, await or promise.
Can anybody please help me achieve the result?

Comment: You _don't_ have async/await, or any promises. Maybe _trying that_ would be a good start?

Comment: I’d do `const test = () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000, "I love You !!")), main = async () => console.log(await test());`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I am receiving undefined.
function test() {
 new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000, "I love You !!"))
}
async function main() {
 console.log(await test());     // undefined
}

Comment: Receiving where? Please [edit] your post and include a [mre].